# Bypassing blacklisted MAC address filtering (that prevents certain MAC address to access router)

Tags: network, mac-address

**PROBLEM OVERVIEW**
I have a access to a large WLAN network (in a hostel); where lot of students have access to wifi password. So, to prevent sharing this password to others I used MAC address white-list filtering. At first everyone share their MAC addresses to me to feed in that filter, which was a heavy and boring work.
One day while modifying a user's MAC address I *accidently* disable all MAC address by clicking on a button. I don't know why manufacturers develop this option; because it also disable my MAC address. Now no one have access to router while knowing password.

**Question**
So, my device have all MAC address in blacklist mode, and I don't wanna do this hectic work to add these addresses again. So, how could I bypass this filter.

**Related Questions**
1. I know about admin password but not have access to network; so any possible way to enter router while connected to another network.
2. A way to disable a MAC address without connecting to that network.

---

1. I already know about bypassing white-list but it doesn't effect because, in this procedure changing my MAC address to connected one is not possible because no one is connected.
2. I can manage any OS on virtual-box; this work could be more hectic than adding these MAC addresses again but I'm curious about this.
3. My router doesn't have WPS button.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in an Ethernet cable?

Comment: Yes I thought about this. But I haven't have one yet. I can manage it tomorrow, but there should be some way of wireless hack. I am just interested that how could it work.

Comment: It's like a question with certain conditions and only one way to solve.

Comment: You want to bypass this filter for just your machine, though. There are lots of ways of recovering, like resetting the device.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can do;

1- Change your mac address and connect.

2- Get a device which is not blocked from the network and connect.

3- Reset your router with a needle.

4- Try plugging an ethernet cable and you might be able to connect.